# action on enter in ember

Tags: ember.js, action

Is there anyway for this text input

```
<input type="text" aria-controls="existing-user-table" placeholder="Search">
```

to trigger an action on the controller when the user hits enter?

I don't like to enclose it in a form tag or create a button, just that input textfield.

Comment: like the sound of this question

Answer (score 29):

Use the `{{input}}` helper - if you include an action parameter it will trigger that action on the controller when the user hits enter. So:

```
{{input action="myAction" aria-controls="existing-user-table" placeholder="Search"}}
```

The [input helper api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input) do not mention this capability, but the helper just wraps [Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html#property_action)

Also it is possible to trigger the action on keyPress instead of enter by specifying the [onEvent property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextSupport.html#property_onEvent):

```
{{input action="myAction" onEvent="keypress" aria-controls="existing-user-table" placeholder="Search"}}
```

Comment: That should be `on="keyPress"`.

Comment: I used {{input key-press="someAction"}} [documented partially here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextSupport.html) - although unfortunately it does not pass the actual key pressed in the event.

Comment: In my case, setting action does not trap the return key in ember-1.8.0-beta.1

Answer (score 29):

The input helper has an `insert-newline` action that will trigger when the user hits the enter key.

```
{{input type='text' aria-controls='existing-user-table' placeholder='Search' insert-newline='myAction'}}
```

[Text Input Helpers](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_actions)

[Insert Newline docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextSupport.html#method_insertNewline)

Comment: This should be accepted answer. If you use ```action``` as previously suggested, you can not get keyCode because you don't have access to the original event. Thanks for saving my time mate!

Comment: how to pass a parameter to `myAction`?

Answer (score 16):

From Ember v1.13.0 the action on input helper is depricated we should use use`enter` or `key-press` instead of `action`

Refer [Ember Docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/input-helpers/)

```
{{input value=someValue enter='someAction'}}
```

this will trigger the mentioned action when the user press enter on the text input

Comment: this is correct for at least Ember 2.0 above. 
someAction(content, event) {
 if(event.keyCode === 13) {
 console.log('enter was press as enter ASCII char code is 13');
}
}